# Weird error on simple query in MsAccess

Tags: ms-access

Any idea what's wrong with the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table1.Description
FROM Table1
ORDER BY Table1.Description DESC;
```

I'm running this on MsAccess on a table where all fields are `Memo`. There are no indexes, primary or anything like that just a bunch of `Memo`s. I'm getting the error `Reserved error (-1060); there is no message for this error.`

If you think my query is OK please let me know because I just had a problem with MDAC being corrupted and had to reinstall so it could be related to that.

**Edit:** OK I narrowed it down so you guys can try to repro:

1. Create a blank database (table `Table1` and `ID` field will be there by default) in MS Access.
2. Add a field called `Field1` of type `Memo`
3. Add some random data and
4. Try to run this query: `SELECT DISTINCT Field1 FROM Table1 ORDER BY Field1`

If you `SELECT *` it will work but won't be uniquer because it will consider the `ID` field.

If you don't get an error please let me know because that would mean my database engine is messed up.

Comment: Try and narrow it down: does `select 1;` work? `select * from Table1;`?

Comment: @Jack: please see my edit.

Comment: Have you seen [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122280/access-query-memo-field-truncation-due-to-distinct/1122512#1122512) answer? It looks like `distinct` does not play nicely with `memo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which MS Access version are you using?

Depending on MS Access version it's not possible to order by memo fields. You will need a workaround like:

```
ORDER BY Left(Description, 127) DESC
```

Comment: Should it work on 2010 version?

Comment: ORDER BY should work with 2010, but it's not really sorting on the whole field content. But the problem in your case is the combination with DISTINCT, as Access is truncating internally the memo field to sort on it (like in my above sample). And that conflicts with DISTINCT.

Comment: Oh I think I got it now. When I use `ORDER BY` a memo, internally, the memo is not being selected anymore but a truncated version of the memo, and can't do `DISTINCT` on a field that is not listed after the `SELECT` statement. Actually for your sample to work I had to also list `Left(Description, 127)` after the SELECT as one more column.